# set variable into queryset of forms.py from my generic view or url

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I want to set a dynamic variable into `queryset` of `forms.py` , I used `__init__` to pass the dynamic variable , I think the code in forms.py is correct, the problem is how to pass the variable in views?

**forms.py** :

```
class ContainerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    vehicle=forms.ModelChoiceField(required=False,queryset=Vehicle.objects.all(),widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      vehicle_id = kwargs.pop('vehicle_id',None)
      super(ContainerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      if vehicle_id:
          self.fields['vehicle'].queryset = Vehicle.objects.filter(id=vehicle_id)
```

**views.py**

```
class ContainerCreate(CreateView):
    form_class = ContainerForm(id= vehicle_id)
    template_name = 'vehicule_app/container_form.html'
```

the error said :

```
Exception Value:'ContainerForm' object is not callable
```

Comment: The error is because `form_class` must be the form class, but you are instantiating an instance. You haven't included enough code to be able to help further. Where does `vehicle_id` come from? How is `id` used by the form?

Comment: yeah you are right ,vehicle_id comes from my model Vehicle

Comment: That doesn't make sense. In your question, you are using `vehicle_id` but you haven't defined it anywhere. Where is the value mean to come from? The url? If so, show the url pattern. You also haven't shown how `id` is used by the model form.

Comment: this is my url : http://127.0.0.1:8000/vehicule_app/1/containeradd/ , the number 1 is the vehicle_id , i don't know how to set it into my view

Comment: You still haven't shown the **URL pattern**.

Comment: and the url that i am using is :     url(r'(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/containeradd/$', views.ContainerCreate.as_view(), name='container-add'),

Comment: OK, so `vehicle_id=1` comes from the URL `127.0.0.1:8000/vehicule_app/1/containeradd`. What do you want to do with it in the view?

Comment: yes exactly , but maybe vehicle_id is an unknown variable , i could not get this number 1

Comment: **What do you want to do with `vehicle_id` in the view?** Use that as the `vehicle_id` for the new container? If so, it doesn't make sense to have `vehicle=forms.ModelChoiceField` in the form.

Comment: each vehicle has many containers , so when i am in the vehicle view list and i want to add a new container i want to see in the forms.py just the vehicle listed .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the `vehicle_id` from the URL, then you can exclude the field from the model form:

```
class ContainerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Container
        exclude = ['vehicle']
```

You can then fetch the parameter from `self.kwargs`, and set the value on the form's instance in `get_form_kwargs`:

```
class ContainerCreate(CreateView):
    form_class = ContainerForm
    template_name = 'vehicule_app/container_form.html'

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(ContainerCreate, self).get_form_kwargs()
        if kwargs['instance'] is None:
            kwargs['instance'] = Container()
            kwargs['instance'].vehicle_id = self.kwargs['pk']  # Fetch the vehicle_id from the URL
        return kwargs
```

Note that the above code will not validate the id from the URL. The user could change it to any value they like.

If you want to keep the `vehicle` field in the form but with a single choice, then override the `__init__` method and set the queryset.

```
class ContainerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Container

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        vehicle_id = kwargs.pop('vehicle_id')
        self.fields['vehicle'].queryset = Vehicle.objects.filter(id=vehicle_id)
```

Then in the `get_form_kwargs` method, add `vehicle_id` to kwargs instead:

```
class ContainerCreate(CreateView):
    form_class = ContainerForm
    template_name = 'vehicule_app/container_form.html'

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(ContainerCreate, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['vehicle_id'] = self.kwargs['pk']
        return kwargs
```

Comment: thank you , what i understand is i will add this code into my generic view , but what about forms.py , i have to change somethings ?

Comment: can you have look in my post please , i updated it for show all the forms.py