# Django - init object has no attribute 'kwargs'

Tags: python, django

I am trying to filter a forms foreign key like in this post [set variable into queryset of forms.py from my generic view or url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43846588/set-variable-into-queryset-of-forms-py-from-my-generic-view-or-url/43847721#43847721)

However I am getting the error

```
'AddSubnet' object has no attribute 'kwargs'
```

when I remove def **init** function then the issues are resolved. so I know its definitely something to do with this function but I'm not sure what.

full trace:

```
Traceback:

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _legacy_get_response
  249.             response = self._get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  62.             self = cls(**initkwargs)

File "/itapp/itapp/sites/views.py" in __init__
  1001.         site_id = self.kwargs['site_id']

Exception Type: AttributeError at /sites/site/add_subnet/7
Exception Value: 'AddSubnet' object has no attribute 'kwargs'
```

views.py:

```
class AddSubnet(CreateView):
    model = SiteSubnets
    template_name = "sites/edit_subnet.html"
    fields = ['device_data', 'subnet', 'subnet_type', 'circuit', 'vlan_id', 'peer_desc']
    exclude = ['site_data'] 

    @method_decorator(user_passes_test(lambda u: u.has_perm('config.add_subnet')))
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.site_id = self.kwargs['site_id']
        self.site = get_object_or_404(SiteData, pk=self.site_id) 
        return super(AddSubnet, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):         
            return reverse_lazy("sites:site_detail_subnets", args = (self.kwargs['site_id'],))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #site_id = kwargs.pop('site_id')
        site_id = self.kwargs['site_id']
        self.fields['circuit'].queryset = Circuits.objects.filter(site_data=site_id)

    def get_form_kwargs(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs = super(AddSubnet, self).get_form_kwargs()
        if kwargs['instance'] is None:
            kwargs['instance'] = SiteSubnets()
            kwargs['instance'].site_data = site = get_object_or_404(SiteData, pk=self.kwargs['site_id'])
            kwargs['site_id'] = self.kwargs['site_id']
        return kwargs

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        site_id = self.kwargs['site_id']
        site = get_object_or_404(SiteData, pk=site_id)
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['SiteID']=self.kwargs['site_id']
        context['SiteName']=site.location
        context['active_subnets']='class="active"'

        return context
```

EDIT:

my form now looks like this

```
class AddSubnetForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SiteSubnets
        fields = ['device_data', 'subnet', 'subnet_type', 'circuit', 'vlan_id', 'peer_desc']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        site_id = self.kwargs.pop('site_id', None)
        super(AddSubnetForm, self).__init__(*arg)
        self.fields['circuit'].queryset = Circuits.objects.filter(site_data=site_id)
```

and my view like this:

```
class AddSubnet(CreateView):
    form_class = AddSubnetForm
    template_name = "sites/edit_subnet.html"

    @method_decorator(user_passes_test(lambda u: u.has_perm('config.add_subnet')))
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.site_id = self.kwargs['site_id']
        self.site = get_object_or_404(SiteData, pk=self.site_id) 
        return super(AddSubnet, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):         
            return reverse_lazy("sites:site_detail_subnets", args = (self.kwargs['site_id'],))

    def get_form_kwargs(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs = super(AddSubnet, self).get_form_kwargs()
        if kwargs['instance'] is None:
            kwargs['instance'] = SiteSubnets()
            kwargs['instance'].site_data = site = get_object_or_404(SiteData, pk=self.kwargs['site_id'])
            kwargs['site_id'] = self.kwargs['site_id']
        return kwargs

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        site_id = self.kwargs['site_id']
        site = get_object_or_404(SiteData, pk=site_id)
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['SiteID']=self.kwargs['site_id']
        context['SiteName']=site.location
        context['active_subnets']='class="active"'

        return context
```

and I'm getting the same error but in the forms.py now

```
File "/itapp/itapp/sites/forms.py" in __init__
  199.         site_id = self.kwargs.pop('site_id', None)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /sites/site/add_subnet/7
Exception Value: 'AddSubnetForm' object has no attribute 'kwargs'
```

Comment: First, try with kwargs = super(AddSubnet, self).get_form_kwargs(*args, **kwargs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never overwrite the `__init__` method on a view.

But looking at your code, it seems that you actually meant to put this - and the `fields` attribute - on the form, not the view.

```
class AddSubnetForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SiteSubnets
        fields = ['device_data', 'subnet', 'subnet_type', 'circuit', 'vlan_id', 'peer_desc']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        site_id = kwargs.pop('site_id', None)
        super(AddSubnetForm, self).__init__(*arg
        self.fields['circuit'].queryset = Circuits.objects.filter(site_data=site_id)

class AddSubnet(CreateView):
    form_class = AddSubnetForm
```

(Note that this is what Alasdair does in the linked answer.)

Comment: so all of my functions should be in the form not the view?

Comment: I'm getting the same error still but on the site_id line in the init of the form, iv updated the question with the new code

Comment: Apologies, that should have just been `kwargs` not `self.kwargs`, updated.

Comment: that did it, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you have not defined `self.kwargs` so it doesnt exist

```
self.site_id = self.kwargs['site_id']
```

should be

```
self.site_id = kwargs['site_id']
```